# Jquery replacing special characters in id selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select an html element that has an id with an '@' and '.' (emails) in it. I found this `.replace( /(:|.|[|]|,|=|@)/g, "\$1" )` online but it doesn't work. This is what I have:

```
elementId.replace(/(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=|@)/g, "\\$1" );

$("div > #" + elementId).empty();
```

It works when I manually escape them, for example `$('#bla\\@bla\\.com')`, but of course that doesn't help me in this case. This is the error I get, which I don't get when I manually do it:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div > #bla@bla.be
```

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: JQuery isn't used for string operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat ID as a regular attribute:

```
$("div > [id='" + elementId + "']").empty();
```

You could also use `getElementById` (to get a jQuery object, say 
`$(document.getElementById("bla@bla.be"))`).

The problem is not that you have invalid IDs as such. The rules for IDs are very loose. The problem is that *CSS selectors* have certain rules for **identifiers**, such as that used in the selector `#elementId`. The value of an attribute, or the value passed to `getElementById`, are not identifiers, they are just strings, which is why they work just fine.

Of course, the best solution is to fix the upstream code so it doesn't generate those odd-looking IDs.

You should be able to omit the `div >` in the above, since IDs are ostensibly unique.

Answer (score 2):

`String.prototype.replace` won't modify the original string, instead it will return the modified string. So you should use its returning value.

```js
var elementId = ":.[],=!#$%&'*+-/?^{}|~;@bla.com";
var cleanup = elementId.replace(/(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=|@|!|\#|\$|%|&|\'|\*|\+|\-|\/|\?|\^|\{|\||\}|~|;)/g, "\\$1" );
var selected = $("div > #" + cleanup).empty();

console.log(selected);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id=":.[],=!#$%&'*+-/?^{}|~;@bla.com"></div>
</div>
```

More about `String.prototype.replace` can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/replace).

Another option is to get the element using [attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors):

```
var selected = $("div > [id='" + elementId +  "']").empty();
```

**Edit** adjusted the regex to replace all the characters allowed in an email address.

Comment: thank you for the reply! I'm going to use attribute selectors in this case since it's shorter.

Comment: My mistake on the leading digits. However, this is still not a good solution (yes, I know it is not originally your solution). It fails to escape many characters that could appear in email addresses but are invalid in CSS selectors, such as `&`. This apparently applies to any of the characters `!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~;` Therefore, if you want to escape, you should use an escaping tool such as `$.escapeSelector()1`,  or its native equivalent `CSS.escape` if available.

Comment: @torazaburo You are right in that point, many characters need to be escaped in order to be used as a selector. I will update my answer.

Comment: @meucas Great. It might be slightly more readable if you used a character class though.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you don't use the return value from [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

If you use jQuery 3, you could make use of [jQuery.escapeSelector()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)

```js
var elm = $("div > #" + $.escapeSelector("bla@bla.be"));
console.log(elm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <div id="bla@bla.be"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your plan is to escape the ID, then this is a great answer. It is **much** preferable to use a built-in such as `$.escapeSelector` (or its native equivalent `CSS.escape` than to write your own regexp.

Comment: @torazaburo The `[` twice in the regex is matching`[` in a character class [`([[\][:.,=@])`](https://regex101.com/r/s2eAhZ/1) as the OP wanted to match that with an alternation `(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=|@)`. But I agree on using a built-in so I have removed the regexp. It was a note for the OP that you could write it using a character class.